# Routing issues with two different pages being active

Tags: javascript, routes, polymer

I have this in `my-app.html`:

```
  <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
  <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subRoute}}"></app-route>
```

It's a fairly standard routing.

One of the sub-pages `my-gigs.html`, which is loaded dynamically (ala PSK) and contains:

```
    <iron-pages id="pageSelector" role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view404">
      ...
      <my-gig
        name="gig"
        route="{{subRoute}}"
      </my-gig>

      <my-city
        name="city"
        route="{{subRoute}}"
      </my-city>
```

In `my-gig.html`, I want to be able to view a specific gig depending on the URL. So, I have:

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:gigId" data="{{routeDataGig}}" active="{{activeGig}}"></app-route>
```

The trouble is that when I go to a different page in the application (say `/city/perth-au`, being displayed from `my-city.html`), the route above is *active* (!). It will have, as `gigId`, `perth-au` (which is totally wrong, since it's obviously NOT a valid ID).

I am lost. Whenever I had problems before with routing, I would use the `active` flag to check if the route was *actually* active. In this problem, I have a problem because `/city/perth-au` and `/gig/445454545` will BOTH satisfy the routing in `my-gig.html`.

What I am doing wrong...?

Ad the moment I am "solving" this by having a check in `my-gig.html`:

```
         <iron-ajax
            id="ajax"
            auto
            url="{{_makeUrl(routeDataGig.gigId)}}"
            handle-as="json"
            debounce-duration="300"
            last-response="{{response}}"
          ></iron-ajax>
```

And then:

```
  _makeUrlIfNotInfo: function(gigId) {
    if( this.route.prefix != '/gig') return;
    return '/stores/gigs/' + gigId;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use for this problem is to check whether the page is actually being shown before processing the slug. I leverage the [`<iron-pages>.selectedClass`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-pages/iron-pages#property-selectedClass) (which has a default of `iron-selected`) and check for that class inside the observer on `<app-route>.data`. [`<iron-pages>.selectedAttribute`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-pages/iron-pages#property-selectedAttribute) is an alternative, but requires explicit configuration.

For example:

```
// template
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:gigId" data="{{routeDataGig}}" active="{{activeGig}}"></app-route>

// script
_routeDataChanged: function(routeDataGig) {
  const isPageSelected = this.classList.contains('iron-selected');
  this.gigId = isPageSelected && routeDataGig.gigId;
}
```

Comment: It's basically the same I am doing -- except that you're checking iron-selected rather than  `route.prefix`... I was really hoping I was doing something totally silly, but well, apparently I am not. `app-route` really seems fundamentally flawed